# How to convert incoming excel file to JSON in Ionic 6

Tags: android, angular, xlsx, ionic6

I am using xlsx library to convert input excel file into JSON and it works fine but when I test on android it won't trigger reader.onload function. Please suggest to me what's the correct library to use for android or what to need to change

```
const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  reader.onload = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e)
    const binarystr: string = e.target.result;
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binarystr, { type: 'binary' });

    const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
    console.log(data);
    this.fileData = data;
  };
```

It doesn't print `console.log(e)`, I've tried try-catch to catch the error but it didn't catch the error as well. Please let me know what's the issue and which library is best for Android  as well as IOS

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Please see the code below, hope it will help someone

```
  incomingfile(event){
     this.file= event.target.files[0];
     this.readXLSX(this.file);
  }

  readXLSX(file){
     let fileReader = this.getFileReader(file);
     fileReader.onload = (e: any) => {
     /* create workbook */
     const binarystr: string = e.target.result;
     const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binarystr, { type: 'binary' });

     /* selected the first sheet */
     const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
     const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

     /* save data */
     const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws); // to get 2d array pass 2nd parameter as object {header: 1}
     console.log(data); // Data will be logged in array format containing objects
     this.zone.run(() => {
       this.fileData = data;
     });
   };
 }

  getFileReader(file): FileReader {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    const zoneOriginalInstance = (fileReader as any)["__zone_symbol__originalInstance"];
    return zoneOriginalInstance || fileReader;
 }
```